# How to write not condition in alert manager route matches?

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

How to write not condition in alert manager route matches?
I want to execute this condition only when severity is not critical..

```
routes
    - match_re:
          severity: ^(?!critical)
        receiver: teams-channel-webhook-high-priority
```

I tried the above regex condition .But it didnt work.

I also tried with

`not_match_re:
   severity: critical`

Even that didnt work.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

`match` and `match_re` have been deprecated in `route` in favor of using [`matcher`](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#matcher)

`matchers` takes a list of conditions (and) and supports regex match `=~` and NOT match `!~` operators.

```yaml
route:
  # root route
  routes:
    - receiver: recvA
      matchers:
        - severity!~"^critical$"
    - receiver: recvB
      # route:receiverB with no matchers will always match if the previous routes don't
```

Comment: Any idea how to express a negative in an `AlertmanagerConfig`?

Comment: `!~`...see the answer you commented on for example of NOT matching alerts with label `severity` `critical`.  If you read the matcher docs linked in my answer, it explains the `!~` means "does not match" the regex.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I read the linked document, it doesn't reference `AlertmanagerConfig` anywhere. I think you didn't read my question very carefully as `AlertmanagerConfig` is not the same thing as "alertmanager's configuration file". For more information, see https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/user-guides/alerting.md

Comment: You should probably ask a new question.  You are asking about `prometheus-operator` which is an independent project from prometheus and relates to additional tools to help run prometheus on kubernetes.  This question/answer is about prometheus/alertmanager config and has nothing to do with the `prometheus-operator` project.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
You can make a nested tree of routes, which in effect gives you an "if ... then ... else ..." capability.

```
 routes:
    - ... something to do always
      continue: true
    - match:
        severity: critical
      routes:
        - ... things to do when critical
        - ...
    - ... things to do when not critical
    - ...
```

Leaving out the "match" condition entirely makes a rule match always.

Note that "continue: true" carries on to the next rule after a match, but only at the same level.  It will only fall out to the parent ruleset if no matches occur.

Or of course, you can explicitly match all non-critical severities e.g. match_re: severity: 'debug|informational|warning'